# It says I need to declare a body because the class is not marked as abstract, extern, or partial, and I don't know what that means

Tags: c#

In my program I have two windows form windows, one that opens by default and another that opens on a button click from the first. They exchange some data and change some text. All pretty simple stuff for the most part. Now I've gotten to the point where I'm getting this error **'charactertest.CharStats.CharStats(charactertest.MainForm)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial**. Which points me to the `public CharStats(MainForm callingForm)` line in my second windows form.

I honestly have next to no idea what that means, I'm sort of familiar with partial, and am kind of fuzzy on body in general (but I'm reading right now). Anyway here's my code, I'm hoping someone can instruct me on the solution and maybe fill me in a little. :)

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public static string VariableLabel1;
        public static string Variable2;

        Random _r = new Random();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();          
        }

        void CLoop()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                SetInfo();
            }
        }

        public void SetInfo(string newText)
        {
            this.pcNameLabel.Text = newText;
        }

        void ChClassButtClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CharStats form = new CharStats(this);
            form.Show();
        }
    }
```

and my second windows form

```
public partial class CharStats : Form
    {
        private MainForm _callingForm;
        public CharStats(MainForm callingForm)

        public CharStats()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _callingForm = callingForm;
        }

        void StatTransfer()
        {
            callingForm.SetInfo("Bob");
        }

        void FighterButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Fighter();
            StatTransfer();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is exactly what error message say - `public CharStats(MainForm callingForm)` have no body (i.e. appending empty one `{}` would fix it)... But it is not clear what part of the error statement you can't understand.

Comment: The error message will be more clear when you understand what abstract, partial and extern mean. All mean "the body of this method is somewhere else".  abstract means "the body will be provided by a derived class", partial means "the body will be provided by another part of this partial class" and extern means "the body will be provided by an external library".  If it's not one of those three things then **you** have to provide the body.

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
public partial class CharStats : Form
    {
        private MainForm _callingForm;
        public CharStats(MainForm callingForm)

        public CharStats()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _callingForm = callingForm;
        }
```

You're probably looking for:

```
public partial class CharStats : Form
    {
        private MainForm _callingForm;
        public CharStats(MainForm callingForm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _callingForm = callingForm;
        }
```

The first tries to declare two constructors: one with a `MainForm` argument and one with zero arguments. However, the body of the second constructor uses a `callingForm` variable, which is not available in that zero-arguments constructor. (This would probably throw a compiler error if you just added `{}` after the first constructor.)

You just want one constructor accepting a `MainForm` argument called `callingForm` and store that in `_callingForm`. Thus, you should do away with the zero-arguments constructor.

Comment: Thanks that was very clear I understand what I've done wrong now.

Comment: @AmazingMrBrock You're welcome. You learn the best from your own mistakes. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your second class you have only written

```
public CharStats(MainForm callingForm)
```

It should be a method (constructor) and should have opening and closing `{}`

```
public CharStats(MainForm callingForm)
{
  //your work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two constructors defined in your CharStats class - one doesn't have a method body and the other references a parameter that doesn't exist in that scope.

Was this what you were wanting?

```
public partial class CharStats : Form
{
    private MainForm _callingForm;

    public CharStats(MainForm callingForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _callingForm = callingForm;
    }

    private CharStats() : this (null)
    {
        // For designer use only.
    }

    void StatTransfer()
    {
        callingForm.SetInfo("Bob");
    }

    void FighterButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Fighter();
        StatTransfer();
    }
}
```